# Boot Dashboard not showing port numbers

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, port, netflix-eureka, sts

Im using sts 3.9 & spring boot 2.4. I can successfully get the tomcat server up & running with my eureka server project, however the boot dashboard isn't revealing the port number, instead just saying the application name & "unknown port" when running

Comment: Hi, please go over [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question

Comment: Ok, what part are you not understanding?